# I want to add cancel order button in woocommerce template order details for guest users only?

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

We are using woocommerce order tracking shortcode.This is my woocommerce order tracking.php file. We track the order of guest users by order id and email.
can we add cancel order button here which can cancel the order of guest user.

```
    <?php if ( $notes ) : ?>
    <h2><?php esc_html_e( 'Order updates', 'woocommerce' ); ?></h2>
    <ol class="commentlist notes">
        <?php foreach ( $notes as $note ) : ?>
        <li class="comment note">
            <div class="comment_container">
                <div class="comment-text">
                    <p class="meta"><?php echo date_i18n( esc_html__( 'l jS \o\f F Y, h:ia', 'woocommerce' ), strtotime( $note->comment_date ) ); // phpcs:ignore WordPress.Security.EscapeOutput.OutputNotEscaped ?></p>
                    <div class="description">
                        <?php echo wpautop( wptexturize( $note->comment_content ) ); // phpcs:ignore WordPress.Security.EscapeOutput.OutputNotEscaped ?>
                    </div>
                    
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="clear"></div>
            </div>
        </li> 
        
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ol>
<?php 

endif; ?>


<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_view_order', $order->get_id() ); ?>
```

This is the view of order details page.
Here i want to add cancel order button for guest users
[image: ![Text](https://stackoverflow.com/image.jpg)]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Use  woocommerce `wc_get_account_orders_actions()` function to get all woocommerce actions.
> Add the following link in you tracking.php file and that's it

```
echo '<a href="'.$string.'" id="custom-cancel" class="woocommerce-button button' . sanitize_html_class( $key ) . '" >' .esc_html( $actions['cancel']['name'] ). '</a>';
```